# Chromecast to Raspberry Pi!

Tags: raspbian, chromecast

I got a Chromecast to replace Dreamplex(not managed by Plex community) on my Satbox which crashes from time to time.

I also tried RaspBMC and RasPlex on the Pi both of which I found a bit slow to navigate the menus, and that it can have like 5 layers before I get to the movie. The payback is crisp though!

But unfortunately no matter how much I tune my WiFi for the Chromecast the video playback is, putting it lightly, "poop"!.

I can use Shairplay for some things via the Rapsberry Pi which is OK but still not ideal. Is there something like a Chromecast emualtor for the Pi, where I can touch play on the Plex App to the Pi Emulated Chromecast and click play from my device, so it plays from my Pi using LAN to my NAS at full quality?

<sup>I am aware of PiCast2.0 but it doesn't do what I ask here. So please dont mention it.</sup>

Comment: Rasplex has improved allot in RC1.4 but it freezes and hangs randomly. Still trying to find something stable for LAN use.

Comment: It should be noted that for most purposes, using WiFi for video playback yields "poop".

Comment: Yea and I wonder why Google didn't think about this. If it was me I would have used the newer (2 year specification) of 802.11.ac that can support up to 1Gbps wireless! And is backward compatible with BGN. Besides on LTE its not poop any more. I might buy an AC router and AC USB for the Pi. See how it goes, use up 100% of USB throughput.

Comment: For the 802.11ac, getting it to work on the RPi might be a challenge. Even bigger perhaps is that the USB/Ethernet chip on the Pi is only USB 2.0 and might be a throughput bottleneck of its own. But I would love to hear that it works! :)

Comment: Yea I understand I might "only" get 250mbps, but that is 8~10 times faster than current WiFi and I am sure streaming my h264 profile 5 files will work just fine and dandy, because it works on my 100mbps LKAN connection on the Pi, so really 802.11ac can be twice as fast as LAN if "just" use it to stream video. @WineSoaked and you know what, I might just buy a router to test this, cause my current BT SmartHub is stupid and slow :)

Comment: Admittedly, the reason it will work (or is more likely to work) is because 802.11ac uses the 5GHz band, not because of (or despite) the Pi's USB chip. #mybad

Let us know how the drivers get sorted out.

Comment: http://goo.gl/dDIzw2 that should do the trick. Just need to save up the pennies. ANd it plugs starigh into my "fibre" and doesn't downgrade my gigbait LAN. nice. Gimme a few weeks.

Comment: @ppumkin have you considered buying the chrome cast ethernet adapter instead: https://store.google.com/product/ethernet_adapter_for_chromecast

Comment: That just reinforces the fact the chrome cast is crap and now we gotta buy some stupid thing for £15. Sucky McSuckThat - send it back get a roku instead